# If I have an embedded unrestricted webview, does that mean I have third-party content?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a unrestricted web view in my app, that I use to access a video on youtube.com. Since YouTube has other content, do I need to say yes to "Does your app contain, display, or access third-party content?".

The the next one is is asking if I have the rights. I would assume because the videos are public, I do have the rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are using third party content.

Yes, you have the rights to display that content as long as the terms of service of YouTube permit it, which it does.

See YouTube Terms of Service (https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) 4 E. Bullet 2:

```
Prohibited commercial uses do not include:
• uploading an original video to YouTube, or maintaining an original channel on YouTube, to promote your business or artistic enterprise;
• showing YouTube videos through the Embeddable Player on an ad-enabled blog or website, subject to the advertising restrictions set forth above in Section 4.D; or
• any use that YouTube expressly authorizes in writing.
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of you both question is YES.

Its absolutely fine with YouTube to use their content publicly. Their [terms and condition](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) confirms that.

Hope this helps.. :)